# Can I create a Substrata server

Tags: raspberry-pi, hosting, virtual-reality

Substrata is a metaverse vr thing; you have to pay for parcels. It says if you host your own server you don't have to buy parcels. There are no instructions on how to do that though. does anyone have any idea how to do this?

substrata.info